# How to pass optional parametr to middleware in from_fn func in axum?

Tags: rust, middleware, rust-axum

**In my axum backend I want to be able to determine what my auth middleware will add to the request: user_id or user model itself. How can I pass the optional full_user parameter to router?
Example of using middleware:**

```
.route("/", post(some_handlers::some_handler::post_smth),
        )
        .route_layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(
            client.clone(),
            auth_middleware::auth,
        ));
```

**I have such auth middleware:**

```
pub async fn auth<B>(
    State(client): State<Client>,
    mut req: Request<B>,
    next: Next<B>,
) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    let auth_header = match req.headers().get(http::header::AUTHORIZATION) {
        Some(header) => header.to_str().ok(),
        None => None,
    };

    let jwt_secret = std::env::var("JWT_SECRET").map_err(|_| StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)?;

    let token = match auth_header {
        Some(token) => token,
        None => return Err(StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED),
    };

    let token_claims = verify_token(token, &jwt_secret).map_err(|_| StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED)?;

    let user_id = ObjectId::parse_str(&token_claims.sub).map_err(|_| StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED)?;

    let collection: Collection<User> = client.database("Merume").collection("users");
    match collection.find_one(doc! {"_id": user_id}, None).await {
        Ok(Some(user)) => user,
        Ok(None) => return Err(StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED),
        Err(_) => return Err(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR),
    };

    req.extensions_mut().insert(user_id);
    Ok(next.run(req).await)
}
```

Tried something like this but it didn't work cause arguments to this func become incorrect

```
.layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(
    client.clone(),
    |req, next| auth(req, next, Some(true)),
));
```

Comment: "It didn't work" → _what_ didn't work? Did it fail to compile? What was the error message? Did it compile but fail to run? What was the output? Did it compile and run but not do what you wanted? What did you want and what did it do instead?

Comment: Aren't you just missing the `state` parameter?  Try `|state, req, next| auth(state, req, next, Some(true))`

Comment: @cdhowie Yes you were right, for some reason I thought that middleware will get the state parameter with client.clone() and I don't need to specify it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the status parameter as @cdhowie was sad in the comments.
Solution:

```
.route_layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(
        client.clone(),
        |state, req, next| auth_middleware::auth(state, req, next, Some(false)),
    ));
```